# Routes and routing specs for restful resources with custom slugs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rspec, slug

I have a `Contact` model which I want to access via a slug in the URL, so I overrode `to_param` like so:

```
def to_param
   "#{self.id}-#{full_name.parameterize}"
end
```

I'm using standard, restful resources:

```
resources :contact
```

This works as expected. The path helpers return the slugified URLs. And the URLs are correctly routed to the controller. So far, so good.

The trouble is that although the slug is routed correctly, updating the routing specs to reflect the changes causes the specs to fail.

E.g. this spec fails:

```
get("/contacts/1-john-smith").should route_to("contacts#show", :id => "1")
```

The original version passes:

```
get("/contacts/1").should route_to("contacts#show", :id => "1")
```

Something doesn't quite add up here. How come the spec is failing when the URL resolves correctly in the browser? And how come changing `to_param` doesn't break the original URL?

More importantly, how do I change the routing declaration so that the spec passes? Can I do this with the `resources` declaration? or do I have to define these routes manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `get`, you're passing an `id` of `"1-john-smith"`, so that's what your controller will receive. Change your spec to this:

```
get("/contacts/1-john-smith").should route_to("contacts#show",
    :id => "1-john-smith")
```

The routing code is indifferent to the slug feature that you've added, and it wouldn't know to strip off certain portions of the `id` parameter. The magic is mostly in `ActiveRecord::Base#find`, because this:

```
Contacts.find "1-john-smith"
```

works the same as this:

```
Contacts.find "1"
```

Comment: Exactly right ~ thanks! I was looking for a way to define the route so that I could parse the numeric ID out of the slug before passing it to the controller, but since `#find` makes them equivalent anyways it doesn't really matter in this case.

Comment: I bet `#find` is just using `String#to_i`, so you could use that if you needed the numeric portion for some reason. `"1-john-smith".to_i => 1`

Comment: Yes indeed. Though the original problem was not how to actually parse the integer out, it was where to hook that logic in to the routing mechanism. Looks like you can only pass whole segments as params to the controller. I don't see any mechanism to parse out variables from a regex for example.